# How to setup and test an Android Library Project with Gradle and Android-Studio?

Tags: java, gradle, android-studio, android-library

I'm working on an Android Library Project utility class (no activity). I tried to test by configuring an other project but I can't make it work, I don't how to use instrumentTest and can't understand for what purpose I should use it (unit test or Activity using my lib).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this tutorial will help you : http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/06/27/a-productive-android-development-environment/ !

Comment: Very interesting post, that what I was looking for. I put you +1